# How can i download and install llvm on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: llvm

I have llvm-6.0 and i=I don't know how to download and install llvm-7.0 on Ubuntu 18.04? Can I install it from terminal or I download from a site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically *two* ways to install LLVM on your Ubuntu 18.04 machine:

- Source
- Binary

Considering your question, it seems you would like to have a binary version of LLVM. Therefore you can install LLVM from your Ubuntu 18.04 terminal as following:

First of all, you should update packages as following:

- `sudo apt-get update`

However, for custom LLVM i.e. in your case LLVM 7:

- `sudo apt-get install -y llvm-7`
- `sudo apt-get install -y llvm-7 llvm-7-dev llvm-7-tools clang-7`

Do you want some LLVM-7 examples?

- `sudo apt-get -y install llvm-7-examples`

Do you want to remove LLVM-6?

- `sudo apt-get purge llvm-6.0 clang-6.0`
- `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kxstudio-team/builds`

For default LLVM installation you should run following (not for your case):

- `sudo apt install llvm`
- For detail packages please check LLVM [Ubuntu nightly packages](https://apt.llvm.org/)

However, currently the last version of LLVM is **LLVM 13.0. 1.** It is better to install the latest version.

Comment: I print in terminal the two commands you told me:                                                                        "sudo apt-get install -y llvm-7 "                                                                                                 and "sudo apt-get install -y llvm-7 llvm-7-dev llvm-7-tools clang-7"                                                             and my system found llvm 6.0. How can I change it?

Comment: May be, first  you need to remove llvm-6. So as I have written the removal commands, in my answer, run  `sudo apt-get purge llvm-6.0 clang-6.0`
and  `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kxstudio-team/builds`

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much for your reply!